# Toggling div kind control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Is anyone come across a control which can perform something similar to `toggling divs` in `win forms`. I am using  `visual studio 2010` and `C#`.
I was looking for a tool similar but couldn’t find.

Please let me know if anyone has an idea

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx)?

[Here is an MSDN on the FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx)

And, from the article:

> The FlowLayoutPanel control automatically sizes to its contents when
>   you set the AutoSize property to true.

So, anything that is not visible will cause the other controls to collapse appropriately

Comment: I think this won't do what I expected. Actually what I was looking is something similar **http://jsfiddle.net/ktYgB/**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Why not? All you are doing is showing/hiding panels. A flowlayoutpanel will allow that.